# Minkowski sum of open and closed set

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A$ and $B$ nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A$ is open and $B$ is closed. Then:
>
> a) $A+B$ is open,
>
> b) $A+B$ is closed,
>
> c) $A+ int B$ is open,
>
> d) $A$ difference $B$ is open.

I can prove option a)   i. e. U (A+b) where b varies over the set B. 
For option b) I have the counter example  $A=(0, 1),B=[1, 2]$ then $A+B=(1, 3)$....
For option c) $A$ is open and $int B$ is open hence their minkowski sum is open, but I am not getting option d

Comment: i tried to suggest an edit but i think messed up some of the formatting. (In your counterexample A+B should be (1,3)

Comment: I am not sure about the exact range you wonder about, so I will try to write the full solution for you.

Comment: @A.P I have written A+B =(1, 3)...I am not getting your point.

Comment: np, I extend my answer

Answer (score 1):

$A - B$ is defined as $\{c| c+B \subset A\}$ this is equivalent to:
$$A-B=(A^c+(-B))^c$$
(I define $(-B)$ as $\{-b|b \in B\}$)

The equivalence holds since $$(A-B)^c=\{c| c+B\not\subset A\}=\{c|\exists b \in N \text{ with } c+b \in A^c\}= \{A^c-b| b\in B\}=\{A^c+b| b\in (-B)\}=A^c +(-B)$$

Since $B$ and  $A^c$ are closed it follows that $A^c +(-B)$ is closed. Therefore $(A^c +( -B))^c = A-B$ is open.

Comment: Edit summary: I changed my answer form a hint to an answer